# I can't understand a sentence in a youtube video (it's for school, please)

Tags: spoken-english, listening

I can't understand the sentence from this video (from 5:44 to 5:50): [Shakespeare: Brief and Naughty](https://youtu.be/9oPe7tG0vYs?t=5m44s&annotation_id=annotation_829350)

Please help, I need this for a school homework!

Comment: What language do you natively speak?

Comment: Is your problem with hearing the words or getting the meaning?

Comment: Can you provide your exact homework assignment related to this video?

Comment: Hearing the words, but I resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is hearing the words here is the answer.

The narrator said first:

> The history plays were often based upon actual accounts of the english
>   monarchy

Then I'm not sure what was the animated queen's words but I guess she said:

> Oh, an empathy.

This guess is less likely to be true but that was the best I could do. Someone can correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Oh, he did say English. But it was "monarchy", the y is kinda hard to hear over the Queen.

Comment: I'd suggest "Oh, the infamy" is more likely than "Oh, an empathy". Possibly related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvs4bOMv5Xw - this is also just a guess, though.

Comment: I agree that the line probably ends with  *monarchy*. As far as what the queen says, it sounds to me like the same thing she says at about 6:02, which **I guess** is 'Oh, I *am* happy' with a slight stress on *am* and it being pronounced like *em*.

Answer (score -1):

I promise it's a throw away joke that you don't need to understand.

Edited: "the history plays were often based on actual accounts of the English monarchy" is the sentence the narrator was saying. I said British before, but it is English.

Comment: I need it. My teacher gave us some question about this video. Please answer (I'm not english, so I don't understand everything this man is saying)

Comment: I can't understand what the Queen was supposed to say either, I think the joke was that she's speaking in that tone of voice. Do you mean just the part the narrator was saying, then? I edited my question to include that.